# short unique id mixed with custom id

Tags: php, mysql, short

What I have is a table with elements. Each element has a unique id and a unique short id, called short. It looks e.g. like the following:

```
id=>short
1 => 1
9 => 9
10=> a
37=> B
```

etc. The short ids are generated via a php function.

what I want to do now is letting the user set his own custom short.
Let's say the 38th user wants his short to be "foobar". The easy solution would be:

```
10=> a
37=> B
38=> foobar
39=> D
```

But that way I gonna lose the C . And if many usersdecide to use a custom short id, that will end up in many short ids lost.

So each custom short will cause the id to be "too far ahead" is there any way to fix this issue? either in mysql or php.

Perfect would be:

```
10=> a
37=> B
38=> foobar
39=> C
40=> FUBAR
41=> D
```

Update: (possible triple row approach)

row "used" only increases, when the short id was generated and not custom made. This way the short ids can always be generated using the "used" row. e.g. :

```
id  |  short  |  used
10  |  a      |  10
37  |  B      |  37
38  |  foobar |  37
39  |  C      |  38
40  |  FUBAR  |  38
41  |  D      |  39
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You'll lose the old short ID ... then what?

Comment: @arxanas: My reading is that the OP wishes to reuse short IDs that were used and have since been released; if so the answer will obviously lie in the code that generates such short IDs, which is not given in the question.  More detail required.

Comment: well I think it is rather stupid to accept answers which just don't solve a problem. I had one non accepted which deserved it, which is now fixed. I'll give out positive ratings for each try of course.

Comment: to shorten the ids I'm using //from http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php with the bases `0123456789` and `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_` . And yes I would love a solution which can recycle unused ids.

Comment: @Wurstbro: That's a fair point. If your past problems have been solved but not by any of the answers given, you could post (and then accept) your own solution.  If they've not yet been solved, you could try editing the questions to provide further information until a solution is forthcoming.  Alternatively, you could delete questions for which you cannot see the community ever finding a solution.  The purpose of this site is not (just) to answer posters' questions, but rather to provide a record of solutions to problems that are applicable to a much wider audience.

Comment: @Wurstbro: If the initial "short ID" is just a base conversion of the "long ID" (which doesn't appear to be the case in your example above), then I fail to see how an short ID can be reused without changing the long IDs?

Comment: @eggyal Maybe I could add a third row, which represents the "used ids" and only increases if NON-custom short ids were generated?

Comment: I added the "third row idea" to the question. Please check it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be simple enough.

1. Create a new table with recycled short ids
2. Create another (sequence) table that holds the last id used for short id generation
3. When a short id gets replaced by a custom one, insert it into the recycling bin
4. When you need to create a new short id, look in the recycling bin first.

   a. if you can find an item, use that as the new short id (and remove it afterwards)

   b. if the bin is empty, increase the sequence by one and generate a new short id from that.

**Update**

This is a simple way to create and use sequence tables:

```
CREATE TABLE seqname (id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=MyISAM SELECT 0 AS id;

UPDATE seqname SET id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
```

Comment: idea looks fine :) If you now tell me how to sequence tables you saved the day :)

Comment: Now im having the problem that if someone creates a custom name like A7 and the shorten function creates that id, everything goes crazy :D

Comment: @Wurstbro maybe step 4b should be repeated until the craziness stops then :)